# White smoke from bonnet and black smoke from exhaust

Tags: overheating

I have a 2009 seat Ibiza 1.6 TDI sport. When running to temp it’s billowing white smoke from under bonnet. I’ve now had 3 different garages take a look, as well as RAC out and no one Knows why. It’s not losing any coolant whatsoever. I’ve recently had the EGR done due to a previous coolant leak, and then head cover gasket done as they thought that was causing the smoke by oil leaking down back of engine. It’s still smoking with no leaks anywhere apparently?!

I’ve also noticed today the exhaust is blowing dark thick smoke on revs and is stinking, but totally different from the bonnet smoke.

Help?!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Has any of the shops looked at the turbo? Black smoke out of the exhaust usually indicates a rich condition, meaning there's more fuel than needed as the engine fires. No clue what the white smoke coming from under the hood would be unless it's a fuel leak (if not an undiagnosed coolant leak).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! To my knowledge I don’t think the turbo has been looked at no! I know the black smoke seems simpler to sort so hopefully that can be diagnosed more successfully than the white bonnet smoke!